# Open specific Accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to visit my site: http://testsite.com/#accordion2 and for it to anchor down & open the 2nd accordion. How do I achieve this? I'd also like this to happen for the first accordion if the url was `#accordion1`.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmjmotb3/

```js
function close_accordion_section(source) {
        $(source).parent().find('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $(source).parent().find('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {     
        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section(e.target);
        }else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(e.target).parent().find('.accordion-section-content').slideDown(300).addClass('open')
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.accordion-section {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}

.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/50x50") top right no-repeat;
}

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 15px 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion1" class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">More information</a>
    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div id="accordion2" class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">More information 2</a>
    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
        <p>Text.</p>
        <p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `window.location.hash` property and go from there.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    if (window.location.hash === 'x') {
        // do x
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Brian. So how do I integrate this into my current solution?

Comment: Hey Michael. Well your current solution needs some tweaks in that just as you have a close_accordion_section function, you should also have an open_accordion_section function. Once you have that, then in dom ready, you would need to call `open_accordion_section(window.location.hash)`. I setup a simple example here, but fiddle appears to be a little finicky in terms of grabbing the location hash so I just hardcoded it at the top of the dom ready handler. http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/su5xxzav/6/

Comment: Absolutely fantastic,  Brian! Yes, I too was getting glitches on fiddle when trying to bring the hash in. I'll add this to my current codename and report back. Thank you!!!